# Can not Use Selenium Driver With Golang Agouti Package

Tags: docker, selenium, go, selenium-webdriver, agouti

I use [agouti](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sclevine/agouti) package in golang. I run selenium docker image, and create a new web driver with the following command:

```
    capabilities := agouti.NewCapabilities().Browser("chrome").With("javascriptEnabled")
    command := []string{"java", "-jar", "selenium-server.jar", "-port", "4444"}
    driver = agouti.NewWebDriver("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", command, agouti.Desired(capabilities))
```

I create a new page and try to set a value of an element in this page. I find element with xpath by using the following command:

```
var selection = page.FindByXPath(xpath)
```

Then try to send key with [SendKeys()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sclevine/agouti#Selection.SendKeys) method of Agouti, but it does not set the value to the element. I tried to send an API call to the selenium by using the [JSON Wire Protocol](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/legacy/json_wire_protocol/#sessionsessionidelementidvalue) of the selenium. In this case, I need the id of the element to send the request. I try to obtain the id of the element with the following code:

```
elems, _ := selection.Elements()
id := elems[0].ID
```

But when I print the id, I saw that it is empty. So my request is not sent. The error I get is like following:

```
 request unsuccessful: Unable to execute request for an existing session: POST /session/bba01dd19db3a063304a40b59b4cefb7/element//value
```

The main reason is of the error is that the id of the element is empty.

Btw, when I use chrome driver it works properly

```
    args = append(args, "disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    chromeOpts := agouti.ChromeOptions("args", args)
    options = append(options, chromeOpts)
    driver = agouti.ChromeDriver(options...)
```

I dont understand why i can not use the selenium in agouti, and why the id of the element is empty. I hope that I explain my problem.
Thanks